# Quartz Scheduler Crontrigger format

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

i'm really confused on the formatting for crontrigger

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger

ive been creating my own format for hours but to no avail :(

Edited*

what i need is to trigger every 10months, based on a specific date.

thanks :D

Comment: What do you mean by 'every 10months, based on a specific date'? How do you want to calculate the trigger based on a 'specific date'? Please add an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: For a concrete answer you should specify the problem better, like has been mentioned above. But eventually this will help you out enough: http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: This website is incorrect anyway. It says the general format is `* * * * ? *` but the `?` should be last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron syntax is too limited to support "*every 10 months*" semantics since 10 is not an even divisor of 12 (you can easily express every 2, 3, 4 or 6 months with cron).

What you need is a [`CalendarIntervalTrigger`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/CalendarIntervalTrigger.html):

> This trigger can achieve schedules that are not possible with `SimpleTrigger` (e.g because months are not a fixed number of seconds) or `CronTrigger` (e.g. because "*every 5 months*" is not an even divisor of 12).

Answer (score 0):

A cron expression is a string comprised of 6 or 7 fields separated by white space [quartz-scheduler.org](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html). Fields can contain any of the allowed values, along with various combinations of the allowed special characters for that field. The fields are as follows:

```
S.NO.  |   Field Name   |   Mandatory   |  Allowed Values   |  Special Characters 
 1.    |   Seconds      |     YES       |  0-59             |    , - * /
 2.    |   Minutes      |     YES       |  0-59             |    , - * /
 3.    |   Hours        |     YES       |  0-23             |    , - * /
 4.    |   Day of month |     YES       |  1-31             |    , - * ? / L W
 5.    |   Month        |     YES       |  1-12 or JAN-DEC  |    , - * /
 6.    |   Day of week  |     YES       |  1-7 or SUN-SAT   |    , - * ? / L #
 7.    |   Year         |      NO       |  empty            |    , 1970-2099 - * /
```

I used [cronguru](https://crontab.guru/) for creating my own cron expression.